# C#.Net Update nuget package using PackageManager

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, nuget-package, auto-update

I have installed Selenium web driver in my .NET desktop application from the NuGet package manager.

**Note**: this is a .NET framework project, not an .NET Core or web project.

Now every time there is a update to Chrome, the older version of this installed package crashes my app. And I have to update it manually. So I thought I can check and update the web driver every time I run my app.

**What I have tried**

```
// ID of the package to be looked up
string packageID = "Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver";
string pathToMyAppFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

// Connect to the official package repository IPackageRepository
IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("https://packages.nuget.org/api/v2");

// Get the list of all NuGet packages with ID 'Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver' 
List<IPackage> packages = repo.FindPackagesById(packageID).ToList();

// Filter the list of packages that are Release (Stable) versions and select the latest version
string latestVersion = packages.Where(item => (item.IsReleaseVersion() == true)).Max(p => p.Version).ToString();

// Initialize the package manager string path = <PATH_TO_WHERE_THE_PACKAGES_SHOULD_BE_INSTALLED>
PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(repo, path);

// Update the package 
packageManager.UpdatePackage(packageID, SemanticVersion.Parse(latestVersion), true, false);
```

**Where I'm stuck**

```
// Update the package 
packageManager.UpdatePackage(packageID, SemanticVersion.Parse(latestVersion), true, false);
```

On this line, I get an error:

> Unable to find package 'Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver'

When I checked my debug folder, I found only `chromedriver.exe` there. I found that NuGet has installed the entire webdriver package in the `packages` folder of the project that I'm working on. Something like this:

```
C:\path\to\VisualStudio\projects\ProjectFolder\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.101.0.4951.4100\driver\win32\chromedriver.exe
```

I want to update this package at form load event itself. I'm not sure if this method will update my `.csproj` file or not.

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider using SeleniumManager or WebDriverManager? Both can automatically retrieve the latest WebDriver for your application without your intervention: var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(); IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);

Comment: @pwrngr: No, I haven't tried that. Do you have a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to handle the latest version of your WebDriver programmatically, you can use either **WebDriver Service** or **WebDriverManager** package - both automatically download a proper version of a WebDriver.

**Selenium Manager** (available since **Selenium.WebDriver 4.6**). It also comes with a benefit of managing your WebDriver's lifecycle for each browser instance.

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("mute-audio"); //just for reference

var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(); //this automatically downloads a WebDriver and passes into your driver instance
IWebDriver DriverInstance = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);
```

**WebDriverManager** - some people still use it. I personally don't recommend it, as it's a third-party library that may eventually become obsolete due to the existence of Selenium Manager.

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArgument("mute-audio"); //just for reference

new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig(), VersionResolveStrategy.MatchingBrowser, Architecture.X64);
IWebDriver DriverInstance = new ChromeDriver(service, chromeOptions);
```